# making a java package in the command line

Tags: java, linux, command-line, package

Though it's probably reccomended one uses and IDE for coding advanced java projects, I personally prefer running almost entirely command-line (using gedit as a text-editor). So please don't just tell me "Just use eclipse!" or something :P

My question is what the method of creating a package in java is by a command.

I'm not talking about packaging an application that runs in the command line, I'm talking about making a package in the command line. Am I making a text file? Am I making a directory?

Relatedly, how does one link to related libs and natives without use of an IDE?

I know I'm being really awkward here, but I really prefer the control one gets working in command line.

Comment: "Creating a package"?  Do you mean "creating a JAR"?  If so, start with the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html.

Comment: nope, jars are easy enough :P I meant an actual package (which, it turns out, is just a directory...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

packages are just directories on the filesystem.
so your package: `com.mycompany.util` corresponds to a directory `com/mycompany/util`.

When running and compiling etc your current workding directory should be where that top directory is located.

To include libraries, include them in your classpath when compiling and running. For example make a Project directory `myproject` and under that have your java-files and packages under `myproject/src/` and libraries that you use under `myproject/libs/`
Then when your current workding directory is `myproject` execute `java -cp .:libs/*.jar`  or the same with `javac`.

But I suggest you look into using ant or maven.

Comment: thats right...packages are nothing but organized directory structures

Answer (score 9):

There are three parts to it: (1) create directory structure; (2) indicate package in java file; (3) compile it.

For example, if you want to create package `com.mycompany.myproject`, then you need to start in the base directory for your project and then:

(1) create directory `com/mycompany/myproject`

(2) create java files in that directory, stating `package com.mycompany.myproject` in them;

(3) compile the files, for example, with `javac -cp . com/mycompany/myproject/*.java`

You may want to specify a different output directory so as to not mix sources and compiled classes.

If you need to use external libraries (.jar files) to compile, then you need to use `-cp` or `-classpath` command-line parameter to `javac` tool to specify them, e.g.

```
javac -cp .:some_library.jar:lib/another_library.java com/mycompany/myproject/*.java
```

It may be a good idea to put all external libraries in one place, e.g. `lib` subdirectory of your main project directory.  And, by the way, the above `javac` command assumes unix-like environment.  If you're on Windows, then you'll need to use `;` for path separation.

Answer (score 2):

You can get along just fine on the command line by using a packaging tool such as [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) or [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html). Maven is especially handy because it is a higher level tool that already knows how to build various project types: command-line apps, webapps, libraries, etc. It also handles library dependencies by downloading them from repositories.

Comment: I don't think this is what OP is after.  He's talking about packages in java source code, not how to package the final app.

Comment: @AleksG - Maven would still be helpful as the OP needs to "link to related libs."

Answer (score 1):

Java Package is just a directory structure, so a simple way of creating a Package lets say com.organization.test in terminal will be

```
mkdir -p com/organization/test
```

Answer (score 0):

// to create a new directory and a subfolder that will be your package

```
$ mkdir -p parent/child
```

// to move into it :

```
$ cd parent/child
```

//to create an empty java file

```
$ touch MyClass.java
```

//to edit current file

```
$ nano MyClass.java

package child; 
 public class MyClass { 
}
```

PS: The directory structure on your computer is related to the package name. That means when you edit .java file it needs to have a package declaration(your package) otherwise you will have a default package (ex: java.util.*).