# What is the correct way to create a Java package from command line? (trouble with Maven)

Tags: java, maven, command-line, package

**[ SOLVED ] - but still looking for explanation. Please see bottom of question**

---

I don't have much experience with command line or with Maven. I'm working on a tutorial from a book. It state I should create a java file

```
src/main/java/com/effectivemaven/chapter01/ExampleAction.java
```

What I did was **`mkdir`** each directory separately i.e. `mkdir com`, `mkdir effectivemaven`, `mkdir chapter01`

I create the .java file in the `chapter01` directory.

```
package com.effectivemaven.chapter01;

import org.slf4j.*;

public class ExampleAction {
    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExampleAction.class);

    public boolean execute() {
        logger.info( "Example Action Executed." );
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I `mvn compile`, it says `compiling 1 file to target...`, but when I look at the taget directory, nothing is created.

So I tried to create a another .java file without using packages, just a simple

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

in the `java` directory, then `mvn compile` and it shows up in the `target` file.

So my assumption is that I'm not creating the packages correctly by using `mkdir`, or possibly I'm doing something else wrong I'm unaware of.

> **So basically I just want to know, what is the correct way to create a package from the command line? And if I'm doing it correctly, what could be the other possible reasons the `.class` is not being created in the `target`?**

---

**EDIT** tree

```
first-webapp
          src
             main
                 java
                     Hello.java
                     com
                        effectivemaven
                                     chapter01
                                             ExampleAction.java
          target
               classes
                     Hello.class
          pom.xml
```

Command running from `C:\Maven Book\first-webapp>`

```
C:\Maven Book\first-webapp>mvn compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building first-webapp Maven Webapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ first-weba
pp ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources,
i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ first-webapp
---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. b
uild is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to C:\Maven Book\first-webapp\target\classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.667s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Jan 12 00:09:49 PST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/111M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
C:\Maven Book\first-webapp>
```

---

**EDIT** pom.xml as requested

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.underdogdevs.webapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>first-webapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>first-webapp Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>first-webapp</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

---

By the way, this is a web-app I created with the following command

> `mvn archetype-generate -DgroupId=com.underdogdevs.webapp -DartifactId=first-webapp -DarchetypeArtifactid=maven-archetype-webapp`

---

**[ SOLVED ] - but with very mimimal understanding** - still offering brownie points for anyone who can explain to me this behavior. Below is what I did

> I got it to work. Since I create the project with `groupId=com.underdogdevs.webapp`, I tried to make a package `com\underdogdevs\webapp` and created a the class with the corresponding package reference. This fixed the problem. The class appears. But I tested it even further and deleted the package I just created and tried to clean and compile with only the original package structure, but the file showed up again in the orginal package structure. I have no idea why this happens though.Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the output of `tree` or similar, and `ls -la target/` from the root directory of the project?

Comment: You should have got an error message when you ran maven.

Comment: packages are just directories for more information you can look [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971838/making-a-java-package-in-the-command-line

Comment: can you share your pom.xml?

Comment: Everything looks okay (no misconception on your side). Try again in the `first-webapp` directory: `mvn clean` and then `mvn compile`. By the way: an IDE might help here, though a bare bones approach gives more insight. You attended about the correct case of filenames?

Comment: @JoopEggen same result, still no `.class` file or package tree created

Comment: can you run Maven with the -X -e arguments, this may provide more information

Comment: @drorb I got it to work. Since I create the project with `groupId=com.underdogdevs.webapp`, I tried to make a package `com\underdogdevs\webapp` and created a the class with the corresponding package reference. This fixed the problem. The class appears. But I tested it even further and deleted the package i just created and tried to clean and compile, but the file showed up again in the orginal package structure. I have no idea why this happens though. Have any ideas?

Comment: @peeskillet the groupId should not have any effect on compilation. The archetype plugin however creates a default class in a package which is the same as the groupId

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the `groupid` isn't related to your application structure -- it's part of your application name. You are building a webapp, so the compiled classes go into the `WEB-INF/classes` directory in the generated war file (which, according to your pom is called `first-webapp.war`) which can be found in the `target` directory. You need directories `src/main/java`, `src/main/resources`, `src/test/java`, `src/test/resources`, `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`. Under the java directory you should put your package structure (more directories), which in this case is `com/effectivemaven/chapter01` and under that put your java file `ExampleAction.java`. Put your `pom` in your project root.

On the command line run `mvn clean install` and you'll generate the target and you should find your `.war` file in there. In that, under the `WEB-INF/classes/com/effectivemavem/chapter01` directory you'll find your compiled java class with a `.class` extension.

At some point you'll have to put a `web.xml` file in the `WEB-INF` directory.